# How to qualify this distribution (it was derived from a multinomial-dirichlet)? Does it exist? Is there a name for?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

What is the name of the distribution below? Is it a Dirichlet-compound multinomial distribution? If not, why?
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        P[\theta_1|\theta_2,\theta_3,\boldsymbol{z},\boldsymbol{\alpha}] &= \frac{N!}{\prod_{k = 1}^3 n_k!}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 + n_1 + n_2 + n_3)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1 + n_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2 + \alpha_3 + n_2 + n_3)}\theta_1^{\alpha_1 + n_1 - 1}(1 - \theta_1)^{\alpha_2 + \alpha_3 + n_2 + n_3 -1}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Note: It is derived from the model:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
    P[\boldsymbol{\theta}|\boldsymbol{\alpha}] &\sim Dirichlet(\alpha)
    \\
    P[z_i|\boldsymbol{\theta}] &\sim multinomial(\boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Assuming $\theta_1$ is restricted to the interval $[0,1]$, it (obviously) is a Beta distribution, because it's in the form $$C\theta_1^{a-1}(1-\theta_1)^{b-1}$$ for values $a,b,C$ that do not depend on $\theta_1.$ However, your formula doesn't make a lot of sense, because no $n_i$ appear on the left and $\theta_2,\theta_3$ do not appear on the right.  Are you sure you transcribed it correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  There indeed is a connection missing as the $\boldsymbol{z}$ explains the n as:
\begin{equation}
n_k = \sum_{i = 1}^N \mathbb{1}(z_i = k)
\end{equation}
Where $N = 3$ in the case of the example above.

Is it clear how I derived the distribution or should I clarify that too?

You are right that there is something of a beta-distribution in there. If I would replace the multinomial distribution by a categorical one I even exactly get a beta distribution. In this case however it is multiplied by the fraction including with the $N$ and $n_k$ in the beginning

Comment: It's not "something of" a Beta: it *must* be a Beta.  The constant in front is merely the normalizing constant. Since it doesn't actually normalize the distribution (to integrate to unity), then it has been incorrectly computed.

Comment: Take the model:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
    P[\boldsymbol{\theta}|\boldsymbol{\alpha}] &\sim Dirichlet(\alpha)
    \\
    P[z_i|\boldsymbol{\theta}] &\sim categorical(\boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Then a known result is that:
\begin{equation}
    P[\theta_1|\theta_2,\theta_3,\boldsymbol{\alpha},\boldsymbol{z}] 
        \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha_1 + n_1, \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 + n_2 + n_3)
\end{equation}
The derivation requires obtaining the posterior and integrating for the other $pi_i$. The results above can be derived parallel.

Comment: Take a look at the Beta-Binomial distribution. That's what I mean with there is something of a beta in. The part with the $n$ gives away that this case it is slightly different. I am quite confident about my derivation, but it might be that I missed something. Furthermore, I like to point out that distributions can be improper. That is, they don't integrate to one. Take for example the Beta(0,0) distribution